# Можно ли в spring в @Profile сделать не конкретные профили, а regex выражение?

Tags: java, spring

Можно ли в spring в @Profile сделать не конкретные профили, а regex выражение?

Comment: Зачем ему regex? Уж лучше наверно EL.

Comment: @RomanC что за el? как использовать